# How to use redis transaction cross multiple classes in spring?

Tags: spring, redis

I have several repositories including many redis operations. My service class invokes them in one method and I want these operations to be one redis transaction. How to achieve it? Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific about what and how you are trying to achieve what you are asking about? That would help provide useful and good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis has two transaction mechanisms:

1. Use [`MULTI/EXEC`](http://redis.io/topics/transactions)
2. Use [`EVALSHA`](http://redis.io/commands/eval)

Choose one, and you are set. A simple Lua script is generally a bit easier than `MULTI/EXEC`, because Lua doesn't need an optimistic presumption (with `WATCH`).

I recommend bundling all commands as MsgPack, and calling `EVALSHA` once, with 1 parameter. This is the most efficient way of passing parameters to Lua.

Hope this helps, TW